# How to add static text infront of value?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay, so I have an output of a value that changes on basis of what you select. 
But I want to have the text "Total €" in front of it like:

[image: this].

But my output now is:

[image: this].

And I would also like to change the "." in the value to a ",".
But every time I add something at places the blocks overlap each other etc. So I hope you guys have some solutions/ideas.

**My html/Styling of the value output:**

```
<h1><input type="yeets" name="_mdjm_event_cost" id="yett" class="mdjm-input-currency required" readonly="readonly" value="" placeholder="Totaal €0.00" style="
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;"/>
</h1>
```

**My value selector:**

```
<select name="iFenceCorners" id="FenceCorners" class="AutosubmitCalculator" tabindex="3">
  <option value="0" selected="selected" data-price="00.00">Geen hoeken</option>
  <option value="1" data-price="20.00">1 hoek</option><option value="2" data-price="40.00">2 hoeken</option><option value="3" data-price="60.00">3 hoeken</option><option value="4" data-price="80.00">4 hoeken</option>
  <option value="5" data-price="100.00">5 hoeken</option><option value="6" data-price="120.00">6 hoeken</option><option value="7" data-price="140.00">7 hoeken</option><option value="8" data-price="160.00">8 hoeken</option>
  <option value="9" data-price="180.00">9 hoeken</option><option value="10" data-price="200.00">10 hoeken</option>
</select>
```

**My Jquery Script:**

```
base = 0;
$("#FenceCorners").on("change", function () {
    var total = (base * 100 + $(this).find(":selected").data("price") * 100) / 100;
    $("#yett").val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
base = 0;
$("#FenceCorners").on("change", function () {
    var total = (base * 100 + $(this).find(":selected").data("price") * 100) / 100;
    $("#yett").val('Total €' + total.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ','));
});
```

Further reading:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp
http://2ality.com/2011/10/string-concatenation.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```js
base = 0;
$("#FenceCorners").on("change", function () {
    var total = (base * 100 + $(this).find(":selected").data("price") * 100) / 100;
    total=total.toFixed(2);
    var suffix = "Total € ";

    var txt = suffix + total;

    $("#yett").val(txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="iFenceCorners" id="FenceCorners" class="AutosubmitCalculator" tabindex="3">
  <option value="0" selected="selected" data-price="00.00">Geen hoeken</option>
  <option value="1" data-price="20.00">1 hoek</option><option value="2" data-price="40.00">2 hoeken</option><option value="3" data-price="60.00">3 hoeken</option><option value="4" data-price="80.00">4 hoeken</option>
  <option value="5" data-price="100.00">5 hoeken</option><option value="6" data-price="120.00">6 hoeken</option><option value="7" data-price="140.00">7 hoeken</option><option value="8" data-price="160.00">8 hoeken</option>
  <option value="9" data-price="180.00">9 hoeken</option><option value="10" data-price="200.00">10 hoeken</option>
</select>
<h1><input type="yeets" name="_mdjm_event_cost" id="yett" class="mdjm-input-currency required" readonly="readonly" value="" placeholder="Totaal €0.00" style="
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;"/>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

For example your total amount is wrapped in a div with the class "amount" you can add the text also via css.

```
<div class="amount">60,00</div>

.amount:before {
  content: "Total € ";
}
```